# Creating a book shelves grid view in android

Tags: android, view, android-canvas, android-gridview

I found this useful [presentation](http://www.sqisland.com/talks/fluid-android-layouts/#32)
and this code is from it :

```
public class BookshelfGridView extends GridView {
  // Constructors etc

  protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    for (int y = top; y < height; y += mWoodPanelHeight) {
      for (int x = mLeftWidth; x < width; x += mWoodPanelWidth) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(mWoodPanelImage, x, y, null);
      }
    }

    for (int y = top; y < height; y += mShelfHeight) {
      // Draw left edge
      // Draw shelf
      // Draw right edge
    }

    super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
  }
}
```

but there are some things that aren't clear such as :

- How to draw the edges. I need a bit of explanation if possible, and if you suggest some topics to study about to understand it, that will be fine.
- What are the variables, height and width ( are they for the GridView ? )

and thanks in advance